# Using Spring MVC with IBM Rational Application Developer

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, ibm-rad

We have to use IBM's RAD (IBM Rational Application Developer) and we decided to use "Spring MVC". My question is that what we have to do to use Spring Mvc inside RAD. Which libraries we must add?

Comment: Whichever Spring libraries you're using. Not sure if RAD would support the latest Spring Tool Suite or not, but you could try.

Comment: I am new to spring and Rad this my problem. I don't know how to do configuration to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what has RAD to do with Spring MVC. In my opinion deploying Spring App in RAD should not be any different from deploying it to Tomcat. Use maven to get the latest of Spring alongwith dependencies, you should be good.

Comment: "Use maven to get the latest of Spring alongwith dependencies" how to do it can you help me. I'm new to spring..

Comment: @faridmovsumov "How to use Maven" is a significantly different question. You have two options: do transitive dependency management manually, which means following the [library requirements](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core/3.0.7.RELEASE) until each dependency's dependencies are satisfied, or doing it automatically via [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/), Ant+Ivy, etc. It may be worth your time to spend some effort using Maven, at least for the simpler use-cases.

Comment: http://www.springsource.org/download should give you latest spring jars... You can manually get the dependencies from maven site